# spawn, expect, send aborts during scp transmission

Tags: linux, scp, expect

I have a basic scp sending mechanism with spawn, expect and send.

However it gets aborted during the scp transmission.

Here is the expect command:

```
expect -c "spawn sh -c {scp -r -P 22 /tmp/rootfs/* root@IP:/.}
expect {
password: {send \"pw12\r\"; exp_continue }
}
exit"
```

This gets interrupted during the scp transmission.

However if I try like this:

```
scp -r -P 22 /tmp/rootfs/* root@IP:/.
```

It will ask for the password, then I type it in, and all the files gets uploaded.

I could not dig deeper yet, what could be the problem?

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/530442/108618) maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kamil comments, consider the `timeout` -- how long does it take to transfer those files?

Also, expect to see the end of the spawned process:

```
expect {
    password: {send \"pw12\r\"; exp_continue }
    eof
}
```